# How to add my own parameters into pymongo find function

Tags: python, pymongo

Im building a python application that allows you to query data from mongoDB based on the start time and end time that the user puts in. I have been able to connect to mongoDB and put data there. I just cant seem to get the query right. I will show only the function in question because I know that connecting to the database isn't the problem, only the query.

```
def query_from_to(self, begin, end):
    self.collection.find("$and" : [ { "x" : {"$gte": begin } }, { "x" : {"$lte": end } } ])
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this format in your function try:

```
collection.find([
            {
                "$Date" : {
                    "$gte": begin, 
                    "$lte": end  
                } 
            }
        ])
```

Comment: You are greatly appreciated! It works! How did you learn this? I didn't see this form in the docs

Comment: you have to experiment a lot in mongodb, i feel.